# Solving a memory leak - Shiny R

Tags: r, memory-leaks, shiny

I have a memory leak with my shiny program, and I'm struggling to figure it out. The leak I have is very small with the code I'll show, but for my actual code it is magnitudes larger in loss, accumulating gigabytes in days. I've been working on simplifying this, but still showing the issue, and this is the best I could come up with. I use three packages, shiny, shinyjs to reset the page, and pryr to show memory loss.

Essentially, just input numbers, and click the submit button to reset/print out memory. If the average of the first two numbers is above 5, it creates a second box. If the average is below 5 on either box, but not 0, then you can submit and reset.

```
    #Library Load##########################################################################################
lapply(c("shiny","shinyjs","pryr"),require,character.only = T)
#ui, shiny body#########################################################################################
ui<-fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  #Div to reset the whole page upon submission
  div(id = paste0("BOX_"),
      h3("Add random numbers. If average is above 5, an additional box will be added. If below 5, click reset to reset the page and update memory"),
      #lapply - Add 2 boxes with double numeric inputs and average
      column(width = 5, align = "center",
      lapply(seq(1,3,2),function(y){
          div(id = paste0("Box_ID_","_",y),
                         numericInput(paste0("Number_",y), label = paste0("Number - ",y), value = 0, min = 0, max = 60, step = .1),
                         numericInput(paste0("Number_",y+1), label = paste0("Number - ",y+1), value = 0, min = 0, max = 60, step = .1),
                         h3(textOutput(paste0("Avg_",y))))
      })),
      column(width = 1),
      #Submit and memory used#########
          actionButton(paste0("Complete_"),"Reset"),
          br(),
      h4("Memory output - Updates on submit"),
      textOutput(paste0("Memory"))
))
#######Server################
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #Reactive Average#########
  Avg<-reactive({
    lapply(seq(1,3,2),function(y){
      req(input[[paste0("Number_",y)]],input[[paste0("Number_",y+1)]])
      if(input[[paste0("Number_",y)]] == 0 | input[[paste0("Number_",y+1)]] == 0) {0} else {
        (input[[paste0("Number_",y)]]+input[[paste0("Number_",y+1)]])/2}
    })
  })
  #Average Output##########
  lapply(seq(1,3,2),function(y){
    output[[paste0('Avg_',y)]] <- renderText({
      req(input[[paste0("Number_",y)]],input[[paste0("Number_",y+1)]])
      if(input[[paste0("Number_",y)]] == 0 | input[[paste0("Number_",y+1)]] == 0) {
        "Enter both numbers"} else{
          paste0("Average = ",round(Avg()[[(y/2)+.5]],1))}
    })
  })
  # Enable/Disable Submit button if average is not 0, and below 5
    observe({
      lapply(seq(1,3,2),function(y){
      req(input[[paste0("Number_",y)]], input[[paste0("Number_",y+1)]])
      if(Avg()[[1]] > 0 & Avg()[[1]] <= 5 | Avg()[[2]] > 0 & Avg()[[2]] <= 5 ) {
        shinyjs::enable(paste0("Complete_"))} else{shinyjs::disable(paste0("Complete_"))}
    })
  })
  #Show next average box if average is not below 5
    observe({
      lapply(seq(1,3,2),function(y){
      req(input[[paste0("Number_",y)]],input[[paste0("Number_",y+1)]])
      if(y == 1 & Avg()[[(y/2)+.5]] <= 5) {
        shinyjs::show(paste0("Box_ID_","_",1))
        shinyjs::hide(paste0("Box_ID_","_",3))
      } else if(y == 1 & Avg()[[(y/2)+.5]] > 5) {
        shinyjs::show(paste0("Box_ID_","_",1))
        shinyjs::show(paste0("Box_ID_","_",3))
      } else if(Avg()[[(y/2)+.5]] > 5) {
        shinyjs::show(paste0("Box_ID_","_",y+2))
      } else {shinyjs::hide(paste0("Box_ID_","_",y+2))}
    })
  })
  #Submit Button - Reset boxes, print memory######
  observeEvent(input[[paste0("Complete_")]],{
    #Reset the page
    reset(paste0("BOX_"))
    #Garabage collect
  })
  #Memory used############
  observeEvent(input[[paste0("Complete_")]],{
    output[[paste0("Memory")]]<-renderText({
      paste0(round(mem_used()/1000000,3)," mb")
    })
  })
}
# Run App
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My best guess is the leak is from the observe/observe events.I have tried the reactlog described here: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1591 But I'm not exactly figuring that what the issue is there. I also looked into this, but I'm not using any outputs in observe: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1551 I had written earlier asking for ideas on how to find memory leaks: [R Shiny Memory Leak - Suggestions on how to find?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52864851/r-shiny-memory-leak-suggestions-on-how-to-find) From that I'm still looking into modules a bit to see if that will help.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: He has acknowledged the other question. Do you have constructive advice on how he can reduce his observer load, or what resource to look at?

Comment: So does that mean I can't use an if statement in observe? And if not, how else do you do something like hide/show or enable/disable? I assumed you could since Deanatali uses ifs and observes for enable/disable? https://deanattali.com/2015/04/23/shinyjs-r-package/

Comment: @PorkChop could you explain why would you want to return anything? The docs say "Any return value will be ignored" and "the return value will be ignored", see https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.7.0/observe.html and https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.7.0/observeEvent.html

Comment: @bers, well unless you know the internal components well, you're not 100% what the `void` function does, I think its better to use functions that return something at the end. Now for the `observer`, as per docs they should ignore returned values, as developers assume you're not doing anything strange or using some 3rd party package which may handle memory differently, e.g. by using too many `assign` as an example or compiling some routines in `cpp`. So I think its best to use `observe` to do light operations and use `reactive` expressions for everything else which return a value.

Comment: @PorkChop excuse my ignorance, but I have a hard time following your comment. "you're not 100% [sure, I guess] what the void function does, I think its better to use functions that return something at the end" - what does the return value of a function have to do with what it does? As the docs say, "observers are only useful for their side effects".

Comment: @bers My main point is `observers` should behave as stated in the docs. Depending on your usage, they may create memory leaks (just google a few you will find people have had issues in the past). So you shouldnt overcomplicate operations inside the observer, and if complicated operations are necessary, use functions which return a value such as `reactive`. Because I don't understand 100% of the codebase behind the `observers` or any other 3rd party libraries you may use inside the `observer`

Comment: @PorkChop I still don't get it. If observers "should behave as stated in the docs", and the docs say the return value is ignored, what makes you think one should "use functions which return a value"?

Comment: @bers Point is, there were a lot of bugs related to memory leaks with `observers` in the past https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/search?p=1&q=memory+leak&type=issues. Given this question is from 2018, I hope they have resolved most of them. Its up-to you to trust the code you're using and the relevant docs, at the same time do profiling yourself also using devtools at least, or now there is a `profvis` package. If in doubt change the code to use `reactive` functions that return a value instead, this is my point

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242109/discussion-between-pork-chop-and-bers).