# Shiny Memory leak R

Tags: r, memory-leaks, shiny

I'm trying to solve a memory leak in Shiny, R. I'm using the pryr package to print memory. Here is some simple code, if I leave this running, the memory will just continually increase. It makes me think either I don't understand memory use, or there is something wrong with shiny/pryr?

```
library(shiny)
library(pryr)

ui<-fluidPage(
  textOutput("Memory"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  memUsed <- function() {paste0(round(mem_used()/1000000,3)," mb")}

  output$"Memory"<-renderText({
    invalidateLater(10)
    memUsed()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I first started trying to solve the memory leaks I was encountering, I thought my only issue was the use of things like observe/observe event, and had asked first a question on how to locate a memory leak: [R Shiny Memory Leak - Suggestions on how to find?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52864851/r-shiny-memory-leak-suggestions-on-how-to-find) Then I had a more specific example of code with a memory leak: [Solving a memory leak - Shiny R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012979/solving-a-memory-leak-shiny-r) Though I've made some personal progress on that front to reduce the memory, I'm still leaking. The amount is certainly small, but after a week this number will increase into the gigabyte range, reducing the speed of my program.

I've tried using the function as is, making it reactive, or just not using the memUsed function and just placing the paste0 into the output to no avail. I've tried this code on both a PC and a Mac and it does the same. I've been trying to identify other related things like: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1253 and https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1591 But I have yet to see anything that at least makes me understand the issue.

Comment: I'd recommend that you fill out your own github issue for this problem (https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/new). It's likely you'll need the help of the shiny developers rather than other shiny users that you'd find on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2267